# Robot reproduction

Tags: technology, xenobiology

For the planet(s) I'm working on I have designed a robot ecosystem, there are 'plants', 'herbivores', 'carnivores'. The only (major) problem I still have is how they could reproduce.
Here's how I think it could work : The robot's main body is made of microbots, which the offspring can start to produce after birth, so most of the offspring's 'exoskeleton' is missing at birth, and it can grow outside the mother's body. The problem with this is that the batteries, furnaces it uses to melt materials that it eats, etc. are made of solid metal or other materials, not of microbots, so the mother organism would need to make those pieces in its body, which would make the 'assembly chamber' or whatever it uses to build it offspring extremely large, which definitely is not advantageous.

My question is: **Can there be another, easier way for these creatures to reproduce, if so, how?**

Comment: This is a brainstorming question. You're asking us to generate ideas and build your world for you. Such questions aren't permitted on this stie. Try asking a more focused question. Have you tried to come up with an easier way yourself? Did you have a particular issue with when you did so? Ask us for help with that more specific question instead.

Comment: Rules are meant to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that your ecosystem would quickly evolve away from individual robots that can each, on their own, perform all the same functions of a biological organism, and toward symbiotic colonies of much more specialized machines.

The process of assembling a robot from raw ores can be broken down into many steps. For instance: mining ores from the ground, smelting the ores into metal, refining the metal and combining it with other materials to produce alloys, extruding the alloys into wire, 3D printing the wire to make parts, and finally assembling the parts into machines.

The vast majority of those steps do not require the machine performing them to be able to walk around. In fact, most of these steps become more efficient the bigger and heavier the machine performing them is- which is directly counterproductive to being able to walk around. Go look up the "[economy of scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale)": There's a reason why, in the real world, tasks like smelting and refining metals are performed in huge, industrial factories.

If you have a single mobile platform that's capable of doing everything from mining to printing to assembling, it's going to be a very inefficient machine. If it wants to make more of itself- a lot more of itself, I mean- its best move will almost certainly be to take whichever steps in the process it is slowest at and build larger, sessile machines capable of doing that more quickly and efficiently.

Even if it takes a while to get the production chain set up, I'd wager that the robots that do build factories like this will eventually end up out-competing the robots that don't.

Answer (score 1):

There are living things and non-living things.

To reproduce and grow, there must be a CELL with LIFE.

**Growth of Robot baby**

You want that there is a small robot who eats steel to grow different parts of body, eats copper to grow wires and motors, eats rubber to grow insulation of wires, eats silicone to grow sensors and circuits, eats lithium to increase battery size and all this is done in a perfect way in perfect proportions. (Remember: human and animal babies eat calcium (in milk) to grow bones, iron for hemoglobin in blood and other metals and non-metals in different forms).

**Food and digestion**

Give the robot baby a food consisting of all the ingredients he needs to grow.  Then devise a mechanism that digests this food to manufacture or grow different parts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will necessarily blur the line between robot and organic creatures.  The problem, as stated, leads to that sole conclusion.

One of the challenges with replicating or healing systems is that we have to think about them differently.  We construct a car by bolting together (and sometimes welding) pieces because that permits us to use the factory tools we have.  When constructing things without a factory, one necessarily must build them different.

Take armor.  We build armor by heating up large slabs of steel and pounding them into shape.  The turtle also builds armor.  It uses a mixture of bone and keratin scutes which grows over time.  Our armor gets its strength through thickness and heat treatments.  Theirs gets strength from *structure*, something we are just starting to unlock in our inorganic creations.

Thus, think about the structure differently.  Don't try to make monolithic batteries.  Try to make charge holding structures which can be grown in-situ.  Don't try to make plate armor in the Main Battle Tank sense, think turtle shells or crab shells.

An excellent source for seeing the kind of adjustments to thinking we have to make is RepRap community.  They are developing an open source 3d printer with a focus on eventually beings self-replicating -- able to make all of its own parts.  The challenge of making circuit boards is a major one right now, and it is forcing them to rethink what a printed circuit board *is*.  They are looking at many clever ways to make them, such as etching the traces into wood and then filling the holes with solder.

I'd also point to the holes in their project as places to explore.  In particular, I am not aware of any interest on their part to replace proper fab-produced integrated circuits.  One still buys them from off the shelf, and puts them into the assembly.  So that may be a place to explore as a worldbuilder.  How could one avoid this step which, at the moment, is necessary.

A direction I would look is analog circuitry.  The modern world (and modern robots) run on digital systems.  But digital systems depend on large numbers of carefully laid out transistors on a very demanding silicon substrate.  Digital breeds versatility, which is why we use it, but many of the hardware requirements drop *dramatically* when you switch to an analog chain.  You might even be able to sidestep electrical controls all together in many cases.

I'd also look at some of the more marvelous "manufacturing" steps that organic creatures do.  Look at the middle ground from both sides!  A personal favorite for me is the development of the retinotopic map, the strangely beautiful relationship between the location of photoreceptors in the retina and where their corresponding connections are made in our midbrain.  The optic nerve grows outward from the retina, following chemical trails that lead it to specific locations such as the superior colliculus.  How these connections are made, and how they map so astonishingly regularly to the surface of the retina is still under research.  However, there's one key detail that I find intriguing for worldbuilding purposes.  Researchers studied this development in rats and found a curious period of time (between 17 and 21 days after gestation, the inner retinal cells spontaneously fire.  These firings interact, forming waves of events that ripple across the retina like a wildfire consuming dry grass.  By 21 days, the photorecptors are matured and we never see this pattern appear again for the rest of our lives.  It is believed this "test pattern" is used to guide the neurons, organizing them.

This I find interesting for countless reasons, but one in particular is that they are sending test patterns on a live system *before* construction is complete.  This is something I find draws a stark line between what I call a robot and what I call a living creature.  In living creatures, the process of construction is in parallel with the process of living.  In robots, we construct them first, then turn them on.

So those are just a few corners that I find interesting to peel back when looking at the question of robot versus living creatures.  Riff on them and see what you find.  Just remember, nature is astonishingly creative.  Take a search through Worldbuilding and see just how many times people asked a question in the form "I would like a creature that does X and Y, but I can't figure out how it could possibly work." and the answer is "here is a species that has already done it!"

Answer (score 0):

Some robots would harvest raw materials. Others would refine the raw materials. Then there would be robots that take the refined material and produce components. At the top would be robots that create new designs. You would see cooperation between the groups. A robot clan. There certainly could be conflict between the clan, especially over access to rare raw materials. There also might be robot robbers, attacking other robots to steal their components.